# Renjin does not recognise german umlauts

Tags: java, r, renjin

I have a file which extensively uses the german umlauts. I wrote a script to process the file which works as it should in native R (RStudio). Unfortunately, while using Renjin, all umlauts are set to unknown characters within the strings of the file. Because of the file-structure, I'm using the readLines-command to read the file. The command read.table() wasn't a proper solution in this case.

I want to use Renjin since I’m working in a Java-team and with the help of Renjin I can preserve our working environment, which of course is based on Java.

Java is recognising the umlauts correctly (uses the correct file-encoding). I also checked whether Renjin prints the umlauts correctly, which it does not. I already tried to set the locale of R within Renjin to “German_Germany.1252”. Therefore I used the following R command:

`engine.eval("Sys.setlocale(category = 'LC_ALL', locale = 'German_Germany.1252')")`

The local is then set correctly. However, Renjin does not recognise the umlauts at all. I checked it while printing one line of the file but also with a single character directly passed to Renjin (using: `engine.eval("print('äöß')")`).

Do you have any idea how to fix this? If not, should I open an issue at github?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that it's an issue with Renjin respecting non-unicode character sets.

By default, Renjin uses Unicode everywhere, and UTF-8 for reading and writing to streams.

If this isn't possible, then please do open an issue on GitHub with a small test file and script.